# What to do in case I have 2 equally good answers?

Tags: discussion

Actually this is not bound to freelancing since I've had the same problems on other SE sites, but the problem I have now is with this topic [How to properly make Retainer Agreement for IT company?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-to-properly-make-retainer-agreement-for-it-company).

Both replies are equally good IMHO and I am not sure which one to mark as an answer?!

Answer (score 1):

The official stance is, whatever answer helped you the most, choose that one. I realize I posted one of the answers, but because it's your choice, you need to decide which one helped most. That's the clear-cut-and-dry way of choosing.